# How to click button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, scroll, webdriverwait

I tried with XPath but selenium can't click this image/button.

[image]

```
from undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome

def test():

    driver = Chrome()
        
    driver.get('https://bandit.camp')
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div"))).click()
if __name__ == "__main__":

    test()
```

Comment: Post the URL and code you've tried.

Comment: Which tag do you need to click? in that tag, which attribute value keeps on changing? Your question is not clear. Edit the question, and add more and a clear explanation.

Comment: I edited, can u look this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one, I checked it, and it is working fine, while clicking on the link it is opening a separate window for login.

```
free_case = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//p[contains(text(),'Open your free')]")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", free_case)
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", free_case)
```

Comment: I got a error.

`Message: element click intercepted: Element <p data-v-e4610dc2="" class="mb-0">...</p> is not clickable at point (285, 914). Other element would receive the click: <div data-v-0d84310b="" class="d-flex align-center px-4 mb-2">...</div>
`

Comment: Updated the code, check it.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to wait for presence of that element.
Then you need to scroll the page down to make that element visible since initially this element is out of the visible screen so you can't click it.
Now you can click it and it works.
The code below is working:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://bandit.camp/"
driver.get(url)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(.,'daily case')][contains(@class,'v-responsive__content')]")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(0.3)
element.click()
```